# Using Azure mobile apps cordova client with signalR

Tags: cordova, signalr, asp.net-web-api2, azure-mobile-services

Wanted to share this for others who might be dealing with the same. If you're using the azure mobile apps cordova client (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-cordova-client) you'll notice there's no support for SignalR built in.

I'm using the built-in SignalR support with WebAPI which generates your SignalR JavaScript proxy file for you to use. But that proxy (or signalR calls in general) will not work when you're got authentication set-up for you API. You probably want to prevent building a separate authentication setup for just SignalR when you've already got the mobile service client going.

Answer (score 2):

So what you do is the following:

Once logged in to mobile services, re-use the X-ZUMO-AUTH and X-ZUMO-VERSION headers like this:

```
var token = mobileServiceClient.currentUser.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken;
var version = mobileServiceClient.version;

var headers = {
   "X-ZUMO-AUTH": token,
   "X-ZUMO-VERSION": version
};

$.signalR.ajaxDefaults.headers = headers;
```

The signalR proxy will now re-use these headers when sending requests to your WebAPI endpoint. This will mean the requests are now authenticated using the same token that the mobile apps client retrieved for you.

Note of caution: I've yet to find out what happens when the token expires or refreshes. I'd advice to reset the headers after every successful login request made.